# How to find element using two link texts that are separated (using Selenium's find element by link text function)

Tags: python, html, selenium, linktext, partiallinktext

I want to find elements using two partial link texts. I want to do this to separate instances where the first link text is the the same as another one.

For example if link text 1 for an element is "Publix Eggs, Large" and link text 2 is "12 ct", and link text 1 for another item is also "Publix Eggs, Large" but its link text 2 is "18ct" I want to be able to find only the first items element if I were to write something like below:

[image]

**EXAMPLE HTML**

[image: link and separated link texts]

[image: what i'm trying to avoid grabbing]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with xPath.

```
//a[contains(.,'Publix Eggs, Large') or contains(.,'12ct')]
```

however, if you are just concerned about fetching the first element, then you can use

`find_element`

```
link = driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Publix Eggs, Large")
link.click()
```

Note that even though there are multiple matching nodes in HTML, it will always pick the first one.

Using `find_elements`

```
links = driver.find_elements(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Publix Eggs, Large")
links[0].click()
```

Comment: doesn't  the "or" in the first solution find the element with one or the other? I want something that finds the element with both "Publix Eggs, Large" and "12 ct" ignoring whether or not it is the first item because I will be for looping it. Because of that the texts being looped need to be unique which is why I want both "Publix Eggs, Large" and "12 ct" because that will make it unique.

Comment: `doesn't the "or" in the first solution find the element with one or the other? ` - it depends on how do you use them? if you would use `find_element` it's gonna return the first matching node irrespective of `or`. If you want that be unique use `and`, it should only look for both the condition `//a[contains(.,'Publix Eggs, Large') and contains(.,'12ct')]`